# I cant figure out to print median correct in C

Tags: c

I need help fixing my median calculations. When I try to print the median value it prints wrong. Here is my code. I need help to determine the median value via the sorted numbers. The program reads in 10 integers from an array and prints out minimum, maximum and average values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

// Maximum
int maximum(int values[]) {
    int Maximum = values[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (values[i] > Maximum)
        {
            Maximum = values[i];
        }
    }
    return Maximum;
}
//  Minimum
int minimum(int values[]){
    int Minimum= values[0];
    for(int i = 0; i  < 10; ++i) {
        if (values[i] < Minimum)
        {
            Minimum = values[i];
        }
    }
    return Minimum;
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
//
    int a[10],i,sum=0;
    printf("enter array\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }



    int max = maximum(a);
    int mini = minimum(a);

    float avg =(float ) sum/10;
    qsort(a, 10, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);


int medianNumber= i/2;
int median=a[medianNumber];

    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    printf("Maximum: %d\n" , max);
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", mini);
    printf("Average: %g\n" , avg);


    //printf("Median: %2.2f\n", median);
    printf("Median:= %d\n" ,a[i]);


    printf("Sorted: ");
    for( int n = 0; n < 10; n++ ) {
        printf("%i ", a[n]);
    }
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Nobody will click on your links. Post your code here

Comment: Please review [ask], and add your code as formatted text and not images.

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: With 10 elements in the array (indexes 0..9), you need to look at `values[4]` and `values[5]` and take their average to get the median, do you not?  So looking at `values[5]` only will produce the wrong result.  Your comparison function is delicate; it would fail if the some of the numbers are big and negative and others are big and positive.  However, if you're dealing with smallish numbers (up to one billion or so), it will work adequately.

Comment: Once you have sorted your array, you shouldn't have to iterate over the entire array to find the min and max. They should just be in the first and last positions.

Comment: float temp, median;

   if (i % 2 == 0){
        median = (a[10 / 2] + a[10 / 2 +1]) / 2;

    } else{
        median = a[10 / 2 +1 ];
    }
I have tried this to, but it rounds up to much

Comment: bruceg,can you please illustrate your thinking with a bit of working code. Maybe try pointing out possible corrections alongside your explanations.

Comment: @KQITA You say "it rounds too much". Please give example input and output of what you mean.

Comment: Oki, the median i get printed from my program 42.9. But it should print 35.5 is the correct answer. Using these numbers:  11 17 27 29 34 37 60 69 70 75

Comment: You are printing "median" with the `&d` format specifier, so I doubt it is giving you 42.9.  Additionally, 42.9 happens to be the mean of those numbers.  Did you misread your output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869700/i-need-help-coding-this-into-a-function-outside-int-main Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You've already marked this question as accepted, and the original scope of this post (printing median correctly) has been addressed. Post a new question to address this new concern and include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
printf("Median:= %d\n" ,a[i]);
```

You are printing element the element designated by `i` in the array, but `i` is just a loop counter.
After you run your loop, i = 10.

But you are calculating the correct array position for median here:

```
int medianNumber= i/2;
int median=a[medianNumber];
```

So you should be printing the element of the array designated by `medianNumber`, like this:

```
printf("Median:= %d\n" ,a[medianNumber]);
```

If you want to take the average for values a[4] and a[5] to discover the median, then you need to do:

```
float median = ((float)a[4] + (float)a[5]) / 2;
```

and then your print statement needs to look like this:

```
printf("Median:= %g\n" , median);
```

When printing, %f will print as many decimals as you tell it to print every time, so %2.2f will always print two decimal places.  %g will only print decimals if they are not zeros, and will omit trailing zeros.

Comment: But should i look on at values[4] and values[5] and take their average to get the median correct`? So when i am only looking at value[5] will produse the wrong answer, and the /2.

Comment: Because the program still prints the wrong median. "Sorted: 31 45 46 51 60 65 66 91 94 96" The Wrong median = 65. But it should print Median = 62.5

Comment: If your goal is to calculate the average of the middle two elements, I have added that code above.

Comment: I have tried the "float median = (a[4] + a[5]) / 2;" But it prints completely wrong median. My goal is to find the median. With using a[5] and a[4].

Comment: That was because your print statement had a %d (for double).  I fixed it above to a %f (for float).

Comment: I see. But now it rounds down to much.  Wrong answer: Median:= 57.00 . Correct:        Median: 57.5

Comment: What input are you using to get 57.5 as a median?  For the input array above that you listed starting with 31, I get 62.50, which is correct.

Comment: That is because it is doing integer arithmetic as the operands are all integers.  Add a float to the mix and it'll do floating point math: `float median = (a[4] + a[5]) / 2.f;`

Comment: Oh shoot I forgot to type the cast to float.  My bad, answer fixed.  Make sure to cast the array elements to float like `(float)a[4]`

Comment: Values i used now:  Sorted: 26 29 33 45 51 76 87 89 97. incorrect Median:= 63.00
Correct median= 63.5

Comment: Try it with casting to float, as I have changed above.

Comment: I have tried that. It still print to decimals to much. for example 47.00  instead of 47. With these values  Sorted: 21 32 34 36 46 48 64 74 75 79

Comment: You can only format a printf to one type of formatting at a time.  If you want it to print only one decimal, then you can format it with %2.1f, so you will get 47.5 or 47.0, depending which is correct.  You have put %2.2f, which will always give you 2 decimals, so either 47.00 or 47.50.  If you want only one decimal, change it to %2.1f

Comment: For example, let's choose these values:
1. 84
2. 13
3. 92
4. 83
5. 20
6. 87
7. 88
8. 54
9. 64
10. 81
Sorted: 13 20 54 64 81 83 84 87 88 92
 It prints that the median is 82.00, but the correct answer is 82

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  If you want to avoid trailing zeros, you need to use %g formatting, not %f as you have.  Answer updated.

Comment: AHHH, now i see

Comment: Great!  If this answered your question, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: _I forgot to type the cast to float. My bad,_  No, you do not _need_ to do that.  a `float` divisor is sufficient ( `(a + b) / 2.0;`  :)

Comment: True, I could have chosen to do implicit casting by using 2.0 as the divisor as well, but one or the other must be done, and it doesn't matter which it is, really, and since their code had /2 as the divisor I chose to cast.

Comment: How do i make it to function outside main?

Comment: That would be a different question, so you should start a new question to ask that.

Comment: I have tried starting a new question, but it got closed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869700/i-need-help-coding-this-into-a-function-outside-int-main Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Issues:

Per the definition of [median](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/mean-median-mode)

This approach:

```
int medianNumber= i/2;
int median=a[medianNumber];
```

Will only work for an odd set of numbers.

Use the following to cover both odd and even sets:

```
//if even number of elements, median is average of two middle values
int medianNumber = 0;
float median = 0;
if(i%2 == 0)//even number of elements
{
    medianNumber= (i/2)-1;//zero based indices
    median=(a[medianNumber]+a[medianNumber+1])/2.0;
}
else // odd number of elements
{
    medianNumber= (i/2);//zero based indices
    median=a[medianNumber];       
}
```

Also, when this for loop exits,

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    ...
}
```

the value for `i` will be `10` causing an *array index out-of-bounds* error here:

```
//printf("Median: %2.2f\n", median);
printf("Median:= %d\n" ,a[i]);
                          ^
```

I would assume that you meant to use the index value `a[medianNumber]`, or more appropriate, use the value you have determined for `median`

```
printf("Median:= %d\n" ,median);
```

The following full code  includes some additional *fixes*, and a `#define ELEMENTS` statement to make testing `even` and `odd` number of elements a little easier to edit.

```
#define ELEMENTS 9  //test for odd and even values

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
//
    int a[10],i,sum=0;
    printf("enter array\n");
    for(i=0;i<ELEMENTS;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }

    int max = maximum(a);
    int mini = minimum(a);

    float avg =(float ) sum/ELEMENTS;
    qsort(a, ELEMENTS, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    //if even number of elements, median is average of two middle values
    int medianNumber = 0;
    float median = 0;
    if(i%2 == 0)//even number of elements
    {
        medianNumber= (i/2)-1;//zero based indices
        median=(a[medianNumber]+a[medianNumber+1])/2.0;
    }
    else // odd number of elements
    {
        medianNumber= (i/2);//zero based indices
        median=a[medianNumber];       
    }

    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    printf("Maximum: %d\n" , max);
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", mini);
    printf("Average: %g\n" , avg);

    printf("Median:= %0.3f\n" ,median);

    printf("Sorted: ");
    for( int n = 0; n < ELEMENTS; n++ ) {
        printf("%i ", a[n]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: But how do i make it to function outside int main?

Comment: @bruleee -   I only included the parts of your code that needed help.  (i.e. those sections in the `main()` function).  `cmpfunc()`, `maximum()` and `minimum()` did not need anything changed.  Just use this `main()` with your original functions and it will work fine.

Comment: Yng, iknow. I have lover all my functions outside main, but i cant figure how to do tur same for median.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869700/i-need-help-coding-this-into-a-function-outside-int-main Can someone help me with this?